# how to create a file with world readable permission under subdirectory of files directory

Tags: android, storage, file-permissions, java-io, android-file

I need to create files under myapp/files/subdir with global permission in my application. I do this because I use external applications to open some files 
Using this

```
 FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
```

creates file only under files folder. Using

```
    File dir=new File(Constants.TASK_DIRECTORY);
    dir.mkdirs();
    File file=new File(dir, FILENAME);         
    file.createNewFile(); FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(file);
```

creates files under subdirectories but with private permissions. I need to find a way to compose those both to create a file in a subdirectory to be world readable

I have been trying a lot of things but none helped me and this was the longest time unanswered question of mine

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but here is the correct way

```
public void makeFileWorldReadable(String path)
{
    File f = new File(path);

    if(!f.exists()) // Create the file if it does not exist.
        f.createNewFile();
    f.setReadable(true, false);
}
```

Comment: Do we know if this is "official"?  Would hate for it to just stop working after an update.  Either way, it solved my problem, probably should accept the answer.

Comment: It's part of the SDK since API Level 9, so any android device running Gingerbread or later it will work on. REF: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html

Answer (score 9):

OP asked how to give access to a file in the following hierarchy: `appdir/files/subdir/myfile`.
The answers provided here don't take subfolder into account, so I feel there's a room for improvement.

In order to access file in hierarchy, a consumer should have **execute** permission on each folder in a path in order to access (read, write, execute) files underneath it.

---

**For API >= 24**

Starting from API 24, Android [restricts access](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html#permfilesys) to `appdir` (a.k.a /data/data/appdir):

> In order to improve the security of private files, the private
>   directory of apps targeting Android 7.0 or higher has restricted
>   access (0700). This setting prevents leakage of metadata of private
>   files, such as their size or existence.

The `appdir` doesn't have world-execute permission, and therefore you can't `cd` into it:

```
angler:/ $ cd /data/data
angler:/data/data $ cd com.myapp
/system/bin/sh: cd: /data/data/com.myapp: Permission denied
```

**Bottom line:** you can give world-readable permission to one of the files in your app's folder, but no other app (as long as they don't share the same Linux user ID) will be able to read them.

Not only that: attempt to pass a `file://` URI to external app will trigger a [FileUriExposedException](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileUriExposedException.html).

---

**For API < 24**

The `appdir` folder has **world-execute** permission by default:

```
shell:/ $ cd /data/data
shell:/data/data $ cd com.myapp
shell:/data/data/com.myapp $
```

Note that even the `appdir/files` folder has **world-execute** permission:

```
shell:/data/data/com.myapp $ cd files
shell:/data/data/com.myapp/files $
```

But if you'll try to create a sub-folder (underneath `files` folder), using this code:

```
File subdir = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "subfolder");
subdir.mkdir();
```

it won't have **world-execute** permission:

```
shell:/ $ cd /data/data/com.myapp/files
shell:/data/data/com.myapp/files $ cd subfolder
/system/bin/sh: cd: /data/data/com.myapp/files/subfolder: Permission denied
shell:/data/data/com.myapp/files $ run-as com.myapp
shell:/data/data/com.myapp $ cd files
shell:/data/data/com.myapp/files $ ls -l 
total 72
drwx------ 3 u0_a226 u0_a226 4096 2016-11-06 11:49 subfolder
shell:/data/data/com.myapp/files $
```

Therefore, you have to explicitly give your newly created folder **world-execute** permission using [File#setExecutable](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#setExecutable(boolean,%20boolean)) method (added in API 9):

```
subdir.setExecutable(true, false);
```

And only then, as suggested by others, you can create your file and give it world-readable permission:

```
File file = new File(subdir, "newfile");
if(!file.exists()) {
    file.createNewFile();
    file.setReadable(true, false);
}
```

Doing that will allow any external application read your file:

```
shell:/ $ cd /data/data/com.myapp/files
shell:/data/data/com.myapp/files $ cd subfolder
shell:/data/data/com.myapp/files/subfolder $ cat newfile > /sdcard/1
shell:/data/data/com.myapp/files/subfolder $ cd /sdcard        
shell:/sdcard $ ls 1 
1
```

Comment: Thanks for the great info! I have two questions by the way.  1. Does any custom subfolder under `/data/data/com.myapp` become private? Or folders under `/data/data/com.myapp/files` only as you wrote here?  2. Are you calling `setReadable(true, false)` because files are always created using `MODE_PRIVATE` mode by default? Or just calling to make sure?

Answer (score 6):

If you are running it on a rooted device, change file permissions using:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chmod 777 " + PATH + fileName);
```

Or try `File.setReadable()`, `File.setWritable` while creating the file.

Comment: well thanks, but I need it for any device, which possibly is not rooted. I think it is a kind of bug

Answer (score 0):

One workaround I used in the past was to re-open the already existing file using openFileOutput in append mode, and pass in the world readable and/or world writable flags during that time.  Then immediately close the file without writing to it.

I like the new methods added in API 9 better though.