# Changing file permissions with Ionic

Tags: android, ionic-framework, permissions, filesystems, ionic-native

I am writing file to device storage using [`@ionic-native/file`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ionic-native/file)'s `copyFile` method.

In Android, it's possible to use

```
file.setExecutable(true, false);
file.setReadable(true, false);
file.setWritable(true, false);
```

I need to do this in my Ionic app so that the file can be successfully used by another application. I've not been able to find any methods or documentation for Ionic that would make this possible.

Does anyone have any ideas how I can accomplish this using Ionic?

Comment: "In Android, it's possible to use" -- [not on modern versions of Android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40513310).

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks, didn't know about that. Wondering if that's the reason there are no methods in Ionic for it